# SCORM 2004 3th edition, all course variables resets after passing

Tags: scorm, scorm2004

I am creating a bespoke SCORM course. All the data that i save and restore works fine. When I finish the course and set the 'cmi.completion_status: completed' and 'cmi.success_status: Passed' I close the course and all looks great in the LMS (cloud.scorm.com).

The problem starts after i try to reopen the course again after completing it. For some reason the LMS is resetting all values that was stored in the the database so it looks like the course was never lunched before.

Any ideas why this is happening and how i can prevent it, since when starting the course i have to make sure that we do not lose the progress of the learner.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to set "cmi.exit" to "suspend" before terminating, that way it knows that you're wanting to come back to the same data, rather than completing this attempt and having the new attempt replace it next time it starts.

Comment: yea, SCORM is very 'intuitive' :)
10x a lot for the answer, this was the problem

Comment: There's so much to read - and the most important bits can be buried in the strangest of places - the conformance docs can be useful for what types of data are allowed too ;-)